# Usar o Crypt do Laravel sem usar o framework?

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso usar o componente do laravel "Crypt" mas separado sem usar o framework, eu instalei ele via composer.

https://github.com/illuminate/encryption

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Illuminate\Encryption;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString('Hello world.');
$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
```

Ele da um erro

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'A facade root has not been set.' in /var/www/html/exec/crypt/vendor/illuminate/support/Facades/Facade.php:218 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/exec/crypt/index.php(14): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('encryptString', Array) #1 /var/www/html/exec/crypt/index.php(14): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encryptString('Hello world.') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/exec/crypt/vendor/illuminate/support/Facades/Facade.php on line 218

Comment: A resposta ajudou você a entender? ou precisa explicar alguma coisa?

Comment: Está dando este erro Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter'

Comment: Dê uma olhada agora na edição se você segiu os passos de instalação! e na edição

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para [baixar o pacote utilize](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/encryption) o comando:

> `php composer.phar require "illuminate/encryption"`

Quando é utilizado fora do `framework` [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) ***utilize a sua instância*** da seguinte forma:

```
<?php include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$key = "0123456789123456";
$c = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter($key);

$r = $c->encryptString('Hello world.');
$s = $c->decryptString($r);

echo $r;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $s;
```

porque, nesse caso a instância precisa de uma ***chave*** no `construtor`. Quando é utilizado no `Laravel` essa chave é retirada da configuração `.env` que no seu caso não tem.

Não se perde nada fazendo assim, inclusive é a maneira correta nesse caso e tem o mesmo resultado que se estivesse utilizando-a no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).

Outra observação é sobre a chave, porque, esse `construtor` pode ser configurado de duas maneiras:

```
public function __construct($key, 'AES-128-CBC')
```

que requer um `$key` com 16 de tamanho,

```
public function __construct($key, 'AES-256-CBC')
```

que requer um `$key` com 32 de tamanho. O padrão é `'AES-128-CBC'`, no exemplo, não foi informado, mas, a `$key` tem o tamanho de 16 como estabelecido.

Comment: Está dando este erro Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter'

Comment: Coloque todo o código na sua pergunta! @TutiJapaWada, e outra coisa o namespace que está usando é errado! o correto é \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter($key)

Comment: Foi resolvido valeu muito obrigado!